# How to write RewriteCond base on directory name character length?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to learn how to apply a RewriteCond based on the length of the "REQUEST URI", or directory name.

So for a three letter directories (/ark/, /pit/, /dyn/, etc), I want to apply a RewriteCond. Currently I am doing this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(ark|pit|dyn) [NC]
```

Which works, but this list can get very long and it seems that it will be easier to use regex or something to select all three letter directories.

Any ideas?

Comment: I believe I have resolved this with 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !([A-Za-z0-9]{3}) [NC]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !([a-z]{3}) [NC]
```

This will match any folder name that has lower case letters and in the length of 3